# Magento 2: Missing Default Inventory Stock and Source

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory

While running the Magento indexer commands I received this `error:  No linked stock found.` After checking the backend I realised that there is no default inventory stock entry or source. I am running `Magento 2.3.2` recently upgraded from `Magento 2.2.6` Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Do you resolve this?

Comment: @EliacimDAVILA-CENSERE Yes I had to manually recreate the default stock and default source from the admin panel. See solution here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Magento-update-to-2-3-compilation-errors/m-p/116037#M1616

Comment: its solved https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/297434/16904